# how to implement SMPP connection to my website (cake php)

Tags: php, cakephp, smpp

We are trying to understand how we can implement smpp connection to our website that is build from `Cakephp framework`.

We want to implement mobile payments (through sms) to our website and we have contacted our mobile providers. They told us that this payment can be implemented only through smpp connectivity.

They have provided us VPN to connect to our server and have access into their SMPP server. And provided us user/password ip to setup the connection.

My question is :

Have anyone implemented mobile payment "through smpp" is there any ready library that can we use?

Thanks
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a really CakePHP specific question. You can just use any SMPP library for PHP, you can find few of them on GitHub (for instance https://github.com/onlinecity/php-smpp) and read your provider documentation.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, our provider hasn't provided any documentation to implement it, they just told us version of smpp 3.4 and type of connection Bind_transceiver type of connection, can you find me any documentation for smpp 3.4 for Bind_transceiver.?